# Locally metrizable but not metrizable space

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, examples-counterexamples

I am looking for spaces which is *locally metrizable* without being *metrizable*. Here are the definitions:

> **Definition.** A topological space $(X,\tau)$ is called *metrizable* if we can define a metric on $X$ that generates $\tau$. A topological space is called *locally metrizable* if every point has a metrizable neighborhood.

I actually know an example, namely the [*long line*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_line_(topology)). In this case I would say the reason is that the long line is (in some sense) *too long* to meaningfully define distancies between its points with just using the real numbers.

So I am actually looking for examples of *another kind* (whatever this means). I know, this is not very rigorous, but maybe someone already knows significantly different examples.

> **Question**: Are there locally metrizable but not metrizable spaces that are not "*too big*" for a metric but fail to have one for another reason? If not, can this be made rigorous in some way?

If something like this is possible, I am looking for a list of "reasons" why a space can fail to be metrizable while still being locally metrizable. Being "too big" might be one of them.

Comment: A rigorous reason for the long line to not be metrisable: it's countably compact but not compact.

Comment: Book tip: non-metrisable manifolds, by David Gauld.  http://www.springer.com/gp/book/9789812872562

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A nice overview paper by David Gauld, whose specialisation is exactly this, gives a lot of equivalent conditions for a manifold (locally Euclidean, connected Hausdorff space for him) to be metrisable.

See [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0910.0885.pdf) and his book Non-metrisable manifolds, as well.
Lots of references there.

A classical metrisation theorem (Smirnov): a locally metrisable Hausdorff space is metrisable iff it is paracompact.

Comment: I liked you answer the most for the last paragraph! This really gave me an intuitive grasp on what is the connection between metrizability and its local counterpart.

Comment: @M.Winter paracompactness (or an equivalent condition) is the global property that glues the local metrisability together to global metrisability (one can use partitions of unity for that, e.g )

Answer (score 8):

The [line with two origins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-Hausdorff_manifold) is locally metrizable but not even Hausdorff. Here the problem is local, in contrast to the long line.

Comment: Nice example, thank you. Do you also have an example that is Hausdorff?